# generar textbox según segun seleccion de Radiobutton

Tags: php, javascript, html

Mi situación es que necesito generar un `textbox` según la selección de un `radiobutton`, y que dependiendo de la selección de el `RedioButton` las propiedades del `textbox` puede variar o tener el mismo nombre, etc. El código que tengo es este, de antemano gracias por la ayuda:

```js
    $(function(){
     $(".op").click(function(){
     if($(this).val()=='1')
     {
    
        var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
        monto_inp.id = "idInput";
        monto_inp.name = "monto";
        monto_inp.placeholder = "cedula";
        monto_inp.type = "text";
        monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
        monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
        document.body.appendChild(monto_inp);
        monto_inp.onkeyup = function() {console.log("onkeyup en input");}
      
     }
     else if($(this).val()=='2')
     {
   
        var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
        monto_inp.id = "idInput";
        monto_inp.name = "monto";
        monto_inp.placeholder = "Passport";
        monto_inp.type = "text";
        monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
        monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
        document.body.appendChild(monto_inp);
        monto_inp.onkeyup = function() {console.log("onkeyup en input");}
      
     }
    
     })})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Documento</label>
    
     <div class="radio-inline">
    
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="1" > Cédula</label>
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="2" > Pasaporte</label> <br>
     
    </div>   <br>
    
     <label >Documento de Identidad</label>
```

En el siguiente codigo se muestra como aplico lo anterior( despues de aplicar el correctivo indicado), la situacion es que no inserta debido a que aparentemente ve como duplicado el nombre del textbox de cedula que es el que genero dinamicamente, la misma la estoy desarrollando en el CMS Wordpress utilizando PHP y MySql.

```html
    <?php 
get_header(); 
if (!empty($_POST))
{
 global $wpdb;
    $tablename =  $wpdb->prefix . "interesado";
 $documentoidentidad = $_POST['cedula'];
 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
 $apellidopaterno=$_POST['apellidopaterno'];
 $cumpleanios=$_POST['cumpleanios'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
 $celular=$_POST['celular'];

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tablename`(`identificacion_interesado`,`nombre_interesado`,`apellidopater_interesado`,`fechanaci_interesado`,`email_interesado`,`telcasa_interesado`,`telcelular_interesado`) 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $documentoidentidad,$nombre,$apellidopaterno,$cumpleanios,$email,$telefono,$celular);
$success=$wpdb->query($sql);

  if($success == true)
 {
  echo
  ' <div id="primary" class="wrap">
    <div id="content" role="main">
 <div id="center">
 <h2>Su Curriculum se guardo exitosamente: ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellidopaterno . '</h2>
    </div></div></div>';
  }
  else {
  echo
  '<div id="primary" class="wrap"><div id="content" role="main"><div id="center">
         <h2>No se guardo su curriculum:' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellidopaterno . ' ' . $id. '</h2></h2>
         </div> </div></div> ';
}} 
else
    {
 ?>

<script>

$(function(){
     $(".op").click(function(){
     if($(this).val()=='1')
     {
        $('#cedula').html('');
        var cedula = document.createElement("input");
        cedula.id = "cedula";
        cedula.name = "cedula";
        cedula.placeholder = "Cedula";
        cedula.type = "text";
        cedula.classList.add('cedula');
        cedula.classList.add('cedula');
        $('#cedula').append(cedula);
        cedula.onkeyup = function() {validate(this.value)}
  
      
     }
     else if($(this).val()=='2')
     {
         $('#cedula').html('');
        var cedula = document.createElement("input");
        cedula.id = "cedula";
        cedula.name = "cedula";
        cedula.placeholder = "Passport";
        cedula.type = "text";
        cedula.classList.add('cedula');
        cedula.classList.add('cedula');
        $('#cedula').append(cedula);
              
     }
    
     })})

</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Documento</label>
<div class="radio-inline">
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="1" > Cédula</label>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="2" > Pasaporte</label> <br>
 </div>

 <label >Documento de Identidad</label>
  
   <div id="cedula"> </div>
   
 <label>Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" name="nombre"  placeholder="Nombre" required>
 <label>Ingrese Apellidos</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellidopaterno"  placeholder="Apellidos" required>
          <label>Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
          <input type="date" name="cumpleanios" min="1925-01-01" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
          <label>Teléfonos</label>
          <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Numero de Casa">
          <input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="Numero de Celular">
      <label>E-Mail</label>
          <input type="email" name="email"   placeholder="E-Mail" required>
   <input class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
   </form>  

 
<?php }  ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error? Que te acumula los inputs?

Comment: @VickMuñoz si es que se acumualan y cuando se genera no aparece en el lugar que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un `div` y ahí agregar el `input` lo agregas con el método `append()` y cada que entre a la validación borrar lo que este en el `div` con esta línea 
`$('#contenedor').html('');` espero sea lo que solicitas, cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
$(function(){
     $(".op").click(function(){
     if($(this).val()=='1')
     {
        $('#contenedor').html('');
        var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
        monto_inp.id = "idInput";
        monto_inp.name = "monto";
        monto_inp.placeholder = "cedula";
        monto_inp.type = "text";
        monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
        monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
        $('#contenedor').append(monto_inp);
        monto_inp.onkeyup = function() {console.log("onkeyup en input");}
      
     }
     else if($(this).val()=='2')
     {
         $('#contenedor').html('');
        var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
        monto_inp.id = "idInput";
        monto_inp.name = "monto";
        monto_inp.placeholder = "Passport";
        monto_inp.type = "text";
        monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
        monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
        $('#contenedor').append(monto_inp);
        monto_inp.onkeyup = function() {console.log("onkeyup en input");}
      
     }
    
     })})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Documento</label>
    
     <div class="radio-inline">
    
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="1" > Cédula</label>
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="2" > Pasaporte</label> <br>
     
    </div>   <br>
    
     <label >Documento de Identidad</label>
     
        <div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: una pregunta adicinal y si quiero hacer un insert como lo hago,

Comment: Insert a la BD con PHP?

Comment: este es el codigo que uso: <?php get_header(); 
if (!empty($_POST))
{global $wpdb;
$tablename =  $wpdb->prefix . "interesado";
$documento = $_POST['cedula']; $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$apellidopaterno=$_POST['apellidopaterno'];
$cumpleanios=$_POST['cumpleanios'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$celular=$_POST['celular'];
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tablename`(`identificacion`,`nombre`,`apellidopater`,`fechanaci_interesado`,`email_interesado`,`telcasa_interesado`,`telcelular_interesado`)

Comment: VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $documentoidentidad,$nombre,$apellidopaterno,$cumpleanios,$email,$telefono,$celular);
$success=$wpdb->query($sql);
if($success == true) {echo
 <div id="primary" class="wrap">
         <div id="content" role="main">
             <div id="center">
               <h2>Su Curriculum se guardo exitosamente: ' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellidopaterno . '</h2>
             </div></div></div>
            ';}
     else {
  echo'
             <h2>No se guardo su curriculum:' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellidopaterno . ' ' . $id. '</h2>
            ';
}} else
    {
 ?>

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Documento</label><div class="radio-inline">
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="1" > Cédula</label>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="radio" class="op" name="documento" value="2" > Pasaporte</label> <br>
 </div> <label >Documento de Identidad</label>
   <div id="cedula"> </div> <label>Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" name="nombre"  placeholder="Nombre" required>
 <label>Apellidos</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellidopaterno"  placeholder="Apellidos" required>

Comment: <label>Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
<input type="date" name="cumpleanios" min="1925-01-01" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
<label>Teléfonos</label>
<input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Numero de Casa">
<input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="Numero de Celular">
<label>E-Mail</label>
<input type="email" name="email"   placeholder="E-Mail" required>
<input class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" /></form> <?php }  ?> <?php get_footer(); ?>   <!-- este es el codigo que uso para hacer el insert, es en wordpress-->

Comment: Agrega todo lo que comentaste en tu pregunta apretando el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/261523/edit);

Comment: ya lo agregue como me indicastes

Comment: En vez de poner `$_POST['cedula']` es `$_POST['monto']` porque es el name que le estas dando al input que creas.

Comment: Disculpa el codigo que puse le faltaba seccion del script, ya se la inclui, no se porque no me lo inserta si todos los nombres concuerdan.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_POST);` para que verificar si esta tomando `$_POST(['cedula'])`.